# Alternative to MLX90614 IR Temperature Sensor : ISB-TS45D?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, sensor, temperature, infrared

Has anyone tried using the "ISB-TS45D Infrared Thermopile Sensor" for measuring temperature using Arduino or any other board. I have used the MLX90614 sensor but is is much costlier than ISB-TS45D.

Datasheet(TS45D): https://www.senbasensor.com/products/infrared-thermopile-sensor-isb-ts45d.html

The sheet mentions a relation of temperature with voltage, should I use an OpAMP before taking readings from arduino as they are in mV or any other circuit is required.